# Elasticsearch filter by multiple fileds does not return document

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-mapping

I have document:

```
{
    "_index" : "logs",
    "_id" : "e174f29c-9f0b-4aab-a3b3-7ab5dcb8a50a",
    "_score" : null,
    "_source" : {
      "number" : 1,
      "request_type" : 1,
      "request_entity_type" : 1,
      "entity_type" : 1,
      "entity_id" : "6c125004-4720-4258-a5d6-3fa1c7468bc8",
      "field_name" : "name",
      "old_value" : null,
      "new_value" : """[{"locale":"ru-RU","text_value":"1234"}]""",
      "created_by" : "b6aa1f8f-79b8-45b6-a11c-fe65b8bdfc35",
      "created_at" : "2022-06-29T10:47:43.205753"
    }
  }
```

And when I try to get this document by `entity_type` and `field_name` fields, it works:

```
GET logs/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
          {"term" : { "entity_type" : "1" }},
          {"term": {"field_name": "name"}}
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "number": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But when I change `field_name` to `entity_id` I get zero hits:

```
GET logs/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
          {"term" : { "entity_type" : "1" }},
          {"term": {"entity_id": "6c125004-4720-4258-a5d6-3fa1c7468bc8"}}
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "number": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Why doesn't it work? What is the difference between `field_name` and `entity_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `entity_id` field is created by Out of the box mapping of Elasticsearch which analyzes it as a text field and break it, adding `.keyword` should work.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
          {"term" : { "entity_type" : "1" }},
          {"term": {"entity_id.keyword": "6c125004-4720-4258-a5d6-3fa1c7468bc8"}} // note `entity_id.keyword` as a field name.
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "number": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Note: If you don't define explicit mapping, Elasticsearch generates both `text` and `keyword` field for every `text` field as it doesn't know your use case.

Comment: Yes, I am going to do it, but now I get "You can accept an answer in 1 minute" message :)